# Without Sauron, who would have been the biggest threat to middle earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

If Sauron had been killed, or taken to the land of the Valar for punishment when Morgoth was finally beaten by the host of the Valar, would there have been an entire age of peace in middle earth, or would someone else who was evil have risen up to become a threat to taking over all of middle earth, and if so, who?

I dont know of another being that was left who would have been strong enough, and also good enough at conquest, and building and leading armies, etc.

---

Edit: I'm new on this site, so can people tell me why this question got downvotes? I thought it was a good question, but because of the downvotes I'm now blocked from asking any questions for two days!

I wasn't meaning that there would be complete peace without Sauron, because of the orcs and evil men that were around. But I think there is a big difference between general low-level threats, and what Sauron was doing to try and master all of middle earth. I wanted to know if anyone else would have been capable of attempting to take over lordship of all middle earth.

Comment: Samwise Gangee seems a nasty piece of work. I could see him overthrowing the West...

Comment: and if Samwise and [Tom Bombadil](http://km-515.livejournal.com/1042.html) had made an alliance, Middle-earth would be coated in darkness forever.

Comment: @R.Skeeter I read your comment in Sean Connery's voice in my head (reminiscent of Indiana Jones and the Holy Grail with his comment about what happens if the Nazi's get ahold of the Grail).

Comment: @holmes200 Are you asking for opinions about who is the biggest bad ass in Middle Earth after Sauron? Or are you asking for citations from the stories showing who is the biggest threat to Middle Earth? If you are asking for opinions, then this is not the right forum. The problem with opinion based questions is that there is no one right answer, nor are there supporting answers. Just a bunch of conflicting opinions. That's why people downvote opinion based questions.

Comment: If Aragorn hadn't released the army of the dead from their oaths, they would be the biggest threat to Middle Earth. The orcs and elves and dwarves would make a grand alliance against the order of Green Ghosts!

Comment: @R.Skeeter "Middle-earth would be **coated** in darkness forever" Coated in darkness instead of covered? I'm imagining this as dark chocolate syrup covering the lands from Mordor to the Shire.

Comment: @RichS Thank you for helping me understand about the downvotes. I did a lot of reading in the Tolkien section of this site before posting, and I was very impressed with the answers, however I didn't get the impression from it that opinions weren't good, as long as they were based on cited evidence from the books. I often saw answers that conflicted with each other, because people drew different conclusions out of different documented evidence, and I would call that educated opinion. But I can see that this question was perhaps too weighted towards conjecture rather than evidence, so thanks.

Comment: I wanted the question answered based on evidence, but I can see that it's not suited to the type of answer that can be given using a simple citation. It involves synthesizing facts about multiple characters and weighing up potential future outcomes, and so that is not ideal for this site. I'll try to make future questions different. However I do see quite a lot of other Tolkien questions posted that to me are not much different to mine - their answers require educated opinion too, which is also, of course, based on cited evidence and a deep understanding of the whole Tolkien universe.

Comment: @RichS I was after who was the biggest threat to middle earth, based on direct citations and/or reasoning based on the canonic attributes of characters. Regards.

Comment: @holmes200 No worries. Welcome to the site. Don't let a few dvs bug you, we all get them from time to time.

Comment: "Yet the seeds that he [Melkor, Sauron's boss] had planted still grew and sprouted, bearing evil fruit, if any would tend them." This means someone else could always become a BBEG (Big Bad Evil Guy), but no one is recorded as doing so.

Answer (score 7):

The only definite statement on this is in the section "Notes on motives in the Silmarillion" in the "Myths Transformed" writings published in History of Middle-earth 10, Morgoth's Ring:

> Manwe knew of Sauron, of course. He had commanded Sauron to come before him for judgement, but had left room for repentance and ultimate rehabilitation. Sauron had refused and had fled into hiding. Sauron, however, was a problem that Men had to deal with finally: the first of the many concentrations of Evil into definite power-points that they would have to combat, as it was also the last of those in 'mythological' personalized (but non-human) form.

There would therefore have been no replacement for Sauron in a "mythological" form, which rules out dragons, Balrogs, Nazgul, etc: Sauron was the final such adversary.

What there *would* have been, either immediately or eventually (Tolkien doesn't say) is an evil *human* leader of some kind.  Again, Tolkien doesn't say *who*, so anything else is speculation.

Comment: "Rehabilitating Sauron" comic strip would be awesome, similar to "Rehabilitating Mr. Wiggles" http://www.mrwiggleslovesyou.com/

Answer (score 5):

There may not have been a single, overarching threat to the Free Peoples with Sauron removed, but that is not to say there were no threats. There would still have been countless Orcs to deal with, who would have been a danger even without their overlord to control them.

There would also still have been large groups of Men who were allied to Morgoth in the First Age, such as the Easterlings of the House of Ulfang. Uldor the Accursed, son of Ulfang, who was deep in the counsel of Morgoth, betrayed Feanor's son Maedhros in the Nírnaeth Arnoediad (the Battle of Unnumbered Tears) in Beleriand.

Dragons were also far more prevalent in the First Age than they were in subsequent ages. The descendants of Glaurung who survived past the end of the First Age would have remained as dangerous and as cruel as ever.

The natural and logical successor to Sauron would have been the Witch-king of Angmar, but he and the other Nazgul did not appear until much much later, when Sauron tricked the Elves into forging the rings, and gave nine of his rings to men under his sway. Some of these men were said to be Black Numenoreans, who worshipped Sauron when he rose to power in Numenor in the Second Age. Without Sauron of course, this would not have taken place at all.

Answer (score 2):

Of the mythological creatures, I would say Smaug the dragon.

Without Sauron's influence, Numenor would have still existed through the Third Age, and the Numenorians might have still become an opressive nation, subjecting the rest of Middle-Earth to themselves.

Comment: Númenor was already on that path, and their attack on Morder that led to Sauron's capture can be seen as part of that process. They had already turned their backs on the Valar, and had been obsessed with death for centuries by that point. Sauron may have sped up the process, but I think an attempt to land in Aman was inevitable.